# How do I add upload, preview, and download features to the Android Cloud application?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, cloud

I'm working on a cloud app with Amazon Web Services, and have successfully configured the sign-in and sign-up process. All I want to know is how to cache that data from cloud and then preview it without having to download it. Can anybody add some script suggestions for that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to cache and for what purpose?

Comment: ok mate i have managed to upload file on the server, but i want to preview those files from server to app as grid view without downloading like thumbnails and allow user to preview or download it like google drive android app

Comment: You don't want to download thumbnails for the grid view? I may have misread when I answered the question.

Comment: Do you intend to cache data like images locally and access them offline?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Lambda function (CreateThumbnail) that Amazon S3 can invoke when objects are created. The tutorial they have walks you through the process for the thumbnails that you want to create.

Make sure you create a separate bucket for your thumbnails. ex. imageThumbnails
Or else, the the source bucket triggers another object-created event, which then invokes the Lambda function again, creating an unwanted recursion.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html